# How do I programatically check if a certain provisioning profile is installed on an attached IOS device using published APIs?

Tags: ios, macos, profile, ipa, udid

How do I programatically check if a certain provisioning profile is installed on an attached IOS device using published APIs? The iPhone Configuration utility can do it - but does it use a proprietary  mechanism?

My lofty goal is to be able to clearly identify is a chosen development IPA from my local machine will install on an attached IOS device without going through any winding roads. Just a Red or Green should display on the screen - if red - the reason should be displayed - profile not installed, device UDID not included or whatever... The app should run on my mac and not on the device.